# Custom Validator not firing JavaScript Function (Client-Side) in ASP. Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Date must be set" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateDate" 
    ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" Display="Dynamic" class="errorMessage">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

This is the custom validator, the client-side function is called `ValidateDate`.

```
function ValidateDate(sender, args) {
    args.isValid = false;
}
```

I wrote this function both in a separate .js file, and in the .aspx file, yet it's not working.

Of course the validation will be bigger, I'm just making a test.

Comment: Mind the case sensitivity. Client-side validator should be set like:  args.IsValid = false;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set `ValidateEmptyText="True|False"`property on your validator to validate empty text. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext.aspx)